# Импорт из yml в инфоблоки Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Посоветуйте пожалуйста решение для импорта yml в инфоблоки Битрикс.
У меня редакция "Старт".

Находил похожее по назначению решение: https://github.com/BedrosovaYulia/bitrix_yml_import

Модуль устанавливается, но соответствующий раздел в редакции "Старт" не появляется.

Может есть у кого решение? или совет как быстро это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru

Answer (score 0):

Сам не пробовал. но там бесплатный период 21 день. На один раз хватит.

http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/kda.importexcel/